# Cardinality of the set of all polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb R$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, polynomials, cardinals

I'm trying to find the cardinality of the set of all polynomials with coefficients in ℝ.
What's wrong with the following proof:

Let $f$ be a function: 
$$f: \mathbb R[x] \to P(\mathbb R)$$
$$f(a_{0}+a_{1}x^{1}+...+a_{k}x^{k}) = \left \{ a_{0}, a_{1}, ..., a_{k} \right \}$$

For example:
$$f(4.3x+2.5) = \left \{ 4.3,2.5 \right \}$$

f is obviously not injective, but is **onto**. 
Meaning that  $$|\mathbb R[x]]| \geq \left | P(R) \right | $$

What am I missing?

Comment: Why is it onto? Can polynomials have an infinite number of coefficients?

Comment: It doesn't look onto to me. What is a polynomial mapping to $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$?

Comment: @Joppy, $$f(3x^3+2x^2+1x^1+0) = {0,1,2,3}$$

Comment: @Olivier, what do you mean? Can a subset of R have an infinite number of elements?

Comment: @Rizon - what about the rest of the natural numbers? I meant the (infinite) set of whole numbers $0,1,2,3,4,\ldots$. A power set of a set is _all_ subsets, not just finite subsets.

Comment: @Joppy, Oh! I admit I didn't know a subset can be infinite. Silly me :|

Comment: You mean the cardinality of **the set** of all polynomials with real coefficients. The cardinality of a polynomial is nothing of interest.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that the cardinality of polynomials of degree $0$ (Only free coefficients) is $|\mathbb{R}| = \mathfrak{c}$ (We just map such polynomials to their free coefficients).

The cardinality of polynomials of degree $1$ is $|\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}| = \mathfrak{c}$.

The cardinality of polynomials of degree $2$ is $|\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}| = \mathfrak{c}$

...

The cardinality of polynomials of degree $n$ is $|\mathbb{R}^n| = \mathfrak{c}$

...

Your set is just the countable union of all these sets from above, and therefore its cardinality is also $\mathfrak{c}$. (See here: [Cardinality of union of ${{\aleph }_{0}}$ disjoint sets of cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57097/cardinality-of-union-of-aleph-0-disjoint-sets-of-cardinality-mathfra))

Answer (score 0):

Ok so look at the interval $[-n,n]$.Total number of subsets of it is $c$...now.coefficients come from one of these subsets for some $n \in N$. So it is less than $c* \aleph $...which is still $c$.The reverse inclusion is trivial.So cardinality of total polynomial is $c$.

Comment: -1 for € and alepnot. Please use MathJax (in which case I'll remove my -1): https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Is it okay now? Typing from comp is ok from mobile its difficult