# Is cardinality a total order? Is AC necessary?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the class of cardinals totally ordered?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69774/is-the-class-of-cardinals-totally-ordered)

Intuitively, it seems like for any sets $A,B$ either $\lvert A\rvert\leq \lvert B\rvert$ or $\lvert B \rvert \leq \lvert A\rvert$. How can I prove this?

Using the definition of cardinality, the problem reduces to proving that for all sets $A,B$, there is either an injection from $A$ to $B$ or from $B$ to $A$. However, I don't see how to proceed from there. Is AC necessary?

Comment: Yes, AC is necessary.

Comment: The proposition that cardinality of any two sets is comparable is equivalent to the axiom of choice. If every set can be well-ordered, then cardinality of any two sets is comparable. And if there exists some set which can't be well-ordered, then by Hartogs theorem there exists a well-ordered set whose cardinality is incomparable to it. (The proposition that every set can be well-ordered is equivalent to the axiom of choice.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the axiom of choice is necessary. Without it you can have an infinite, [Dedekind-finite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind-infinite_set) set. If $A$ is such a set, there is no injection of $\omega$ into $A$ and no injection of $A$ into $\omega$.