# Axiom of choice , Hartogs ordinals, well-ordering principle

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

I'm trying to prove the following:

If it holds that if for any two sets $A$ and $B$, $A$ can be injected into $B$ or $B$ can be injected into $A$, then every set can be well-ordered (axiom of choice variant).

I intend to use Hartogs ordinal, but I am not very sure... my idea is that:
Assuming that $A$ and $B$ have different cardinal number, and that $A$ can be injected into $B$, then $|A|<|B|$. Considering the Hartogs ordinals $H(A)$ and $H(B)$ of $A$ and $B$, I think that I can assume that $|H(A)|<|H(B)|$, then it should exist an injection from  $H(A)$ to $B$, otherwise, $H(A)$ would be the Hartogs ordinal of $B$.

I'm not sure if this reasoning is correct how to continue it, I'm just beginning to study the axiom of choice...

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: By the way, Hartogs is the correct way to write that name, it's not Hartog.

Comment: You can find different answers here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268942/for-any-two-sets-a-b-a-leqb-or-b-leqa/268952#268952

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Compare $A$ with its Hartogs. Conclude that $A$ can be injected into an ordinal and can therefore be well-ordered.