# If $A\sim B$(both dedekind infinite), is it then that $A\sim B\cup \{x\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

If the symbol $A\sim B $signifies that there is a bijection between  A and B, and We take our sets to be dedekind infinite, then is the following correct? If not, what is the counter example?:$$A \sim B \Rightarrow A \sim B\cup\{x\}$$

Comment: Which of the definitions of Dedekind-infinite are you using?

Comment: If A is dedekind infinite,then there is an injection (which is not surjective), from A to itself.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f : A \to B$ be a bijection, and fix an injection $g : \mathbb{N} \to A$, which exists since $A$ is Dedekind-infinite, and let $a_n=g(n)$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Define $f' : A \to B \cup \{ x \}$ by letting
$$f'(a) = \begin{cases} f(a) & \text{if } a \not\in \mathrm{im}(g) \\ x & \text{if } a=a_0 \\ f(a_{n-1}) & \text{if } a=a_n \text{ for some } n>0 \end{cases}$$
You need to prove that $f'$ is a bijection.

Comment: Thank you for answering. This question was asked as I  was trying to reason about the Schröder-Bernstein theorem. I unfortunately fail to see the insight(The idea of why you use the methods you do).

Comment: @user13910: I came up with the solution by thinking about what I knew about Dedekind-infinite sets, and pondering whether any of the things I knew might help me answer this question. The goal was to find a way of turning a bijection $A \to B$ into a bijection $A \to B \cup \{ x \}$. A set $A$ is Dedekind-infinite if and only if there is an injection $\mathbb{N} \to A$, and so 'bumping' all the elements of $A$ in this function opened up a 'gap' that I could fill with $x$. And then fleshing out the details to make this precise led to the function $f'$ that you see in my answer.

Comment: P.S. I've changed the notation in the answer slightly to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the [axiom of choice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180951/is-cardinality-a-total-order-is-ac-necessary), cardinality is a total order; equivalently, every set is well ordered. Now think of ordinals and each element associated with exactly one ordinal.

Comment: The axiom of choice has no business being involved here.

Comment: It could not, but I *can*. And it works.

Comment: @AsafKaragila isn't it the case that AC is somewhat involved here? https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1396713

Comment: @StupidQuestionsInc: No, choice is involved in making sure every infinite set is Dedekind infinite. But here it is given, thus no choice is needed.

Comment: @AsafKaragila thank you $\mathsf{AC}$ master