Proof that cardinal order is linear
Let $X, Y$ be two sets. We define the equality of cardinality as follows: $|X| = |Y|$ if and only if there exists bijection between $X$ and $Y$. And, $|X| \leq |Y|$ if and only if there exists one-to-one function between $X$ and $Y$. Finally, $|X| < |Y|$ if and only if $|X| \leq |Y|$ and $|X| \neq |Y|$.

Prove that $<$ is linear.

Why is the ordering follows trichotomy? The book states "It follows from the axiom of choice that it must be linear".

You might want to look up equivalences to axiom of choice, I believe there is one regarding orders.

Obligatory linguistic note: semantically, "between $X$ and $Y$" is symmetric, so you shouldn't use that for a relation that may not be symmetric.  "One-to-one function from $X$ to $Y$" is better.

You can assume AOC, then use Zorn's lemma to prove every two sets are comparable. See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268942/for-any-two-sets-a-b-a-leqb-or-b-leqa

@AngaeMT My book did not mention Zorn's. There should exist an alternative.

Then maybe this link can help you https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/421638/proving-a-le-b-vee-b-le-a-for-sets-a-and-b?noredirect=1&lq=1
