# $A \times B\,$ equivalence to $N$. If yes then how?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A$ is a set of odd numbers and $B$ is the set of even number, then is their product = set of natural numbers ?? In other word, how can we define a map $f: A\times B \rightarrow\mathbf{N}$ and prove the bijection of that function?

Comment: The answer to the first question is no. This renders the second question useless.

Comment: I think Danish must be talking about cardinality, because the question makes no sense otherwise. In which case the answer to the first question would be yes, and my only comment is that it's easier to find two injections that it is a single bijection.

Comment: Even even if he means cardinaly instead of equality, the answer to the first question is still no. Consider $A=\{1\}$ and $B=\{2\}$.

Comment: Again, I think that's just down to Danish writing the question out incorrectly.

Comment: Simply i need to prove :
AxB ~ N is bijective.

Comment: @DanishButt Read my comment above.

Comment: @GitGud No there exist the bijectivity because it has used in order to solve the problem of cardinal numbers.

Comment: If we take the question literally, then $A$ is a *subset* of the odd numbers, whereas $B$ are all of the even numbers. Hence, the answer is "yes" iff $A \ne \emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: There is standard theorem witch says that for infinite set $X$, $|X\times X|=|X|$. Try to find bijections $B\rightarrow N$, $A\rightarrow N$. Use theorem (or proof of this theorem if you want bijection not only equality of cardinalities).

Comment: Doesn't that rely on the axiom of choice in general?

Comment: I guess it does. At least i would prove this well ordering X.

Comment: If i remember correctly equivalence ($|X|\le|Y|$ and $|X|\ge|Y|$) iff $|X|=|Y|$ require AC too.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's right or not, but I did find this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69774/is-the-class-of-cardinals-totally-ordered

Nevermind, it's not true. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Bernstein%E2%80%93Schroeder_theorem

Comment: Zermelo's theorem says that fact that every set can be well ordered is equivalent to AC.

Comment: It is interesting tho how strong theory ZF + Cantor theorem is.

Comment: @user52045: Cantor's theorem is provable in ZF; for infinite well-ordered sets $A$ it is true in ZF that $|A|=|A\times A|$. Countable sets are well-ordered by definition.

Comment: Ofc but can you tell something about ZF + Cantor or is this for some reason not interesting.

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. Adding to ZF a theorem of ZF doesn't add any new consequences. Cantor's theorem is a theorem of ZF, so adding it as an explicit axiom doesn't add any new consequences to ZF.

Comment: I know that cantor works in ZF if you apply it only to well ordered sets. But i dont think it does if we cant well order set $X$. My question is if its stronger if i have Cantor for all sets without having them well ordered. I dont think cardinals are well ordered without AC.

Comment: No, Cantor's theorem about the size of power sets is true for every set in ZF.

Comment: Sorry i meant Cantor–Bernstein–Schroeder theorem i thought its obvious form the previous comments.

Comment: That theorem is also provable for every two sets in ZF. What is not true anymore is that we can use surjections instead if injections.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I guess i have to look at this one more time. It was a long time ago.

Answer (score 0):

We know that 
         N~E       where N is set of natural no and E is set of even no.

Its mean that there exist a map such as

```
     f:N--->E   (which is bijective)
```

similarly
         N~O        where N is set of natural no and O is set of Odd no.
Such as 
         g:N--->O   (which is bijective)
So
there exist a map such as:

```
     h:NxN ---> ExO
     h(m,n)=(f(m),g(n)) for all m,n belongs to N.
```

This is bijective.
So
NxN ~ ExO
And N ~ NxN which implies that
N ~ ExO