# About sets and injections

Tags: set-theory

Let $A,B$ be two sets.

Is there necessarily an injection from $A$ to $B$ or an injection from $B$ to $A$ ?

Comment: Try using finite $A$'s and $B$'s.

Comment: @kingW3 How is that helpful?

Comment: See also: [Is the class of cardinals totally ordered?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/69774)

Comment: @NormalHuman I guess it was a bit of a broad statement,anyway I had my intentions how to lead him to answer.

Comment: Doesn't "|A|< |B|" or "A has smaller cardinality than B" MEAN there exist an injective function from A to B that is not a surjection?  If not, what definition of "<" are you using.