# Assume for any arbitrary sets $A,B$ if there is a onto map from $A\to B$, then $\exists$ a one-one map from $B\to A$. Prove the Axiom of Choice.

Tags: functions, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I want to prove that - 
*(Axiom of Choice)* Let $I$ be a set and for each $\alpha\in I$ let $X_\alpha$ be a non-empty set. Suppose that $X_\alpha \cap X_\beta=\emptyset$ for all $\alpha\ne\beta$. Then there is a set $Y$ such that $|Y\cap X_\alpha|=1\ \forall \alpha\in I$.
Here I take $A=\bigcup_{\alpha\in I} X_\alpha$ and $B=I$ and define $g:A\to B$ be $g(x)=\alpha$ if $x_\alpha\in X_\alpha$. This map $g$ is well defined from the fact that $X_\alpha\cap X_\beta=\emptyset$. Again $g$ is onto because $X_\alpha\ne \emptyset \ \forall \alpha\in I$.
So by our given hypothesis $\exists$ an injective map $f:I\to\bigcup_{\alpha\in I}X_\alpha$. But it doesn't imply that $f(\alpha)\in X_\alpha\ \forall \alpha\in I$.
Can anyone help me to complete the proof?

Comment: The statement should maybe be that $f$ obeys $f \circ g = \textrm{id}_A$ as well, instead of the existence of a 1-1 $f$. Or use that comparability of cardinals implies AC. See e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1996533/4280) and its answers

Comment: You are trying to prove that the Partition Principle implies the Axiom of Choice; this is [not known to be true](http://karagila.org/2014/on-the-partition-principle/).

Comment: @Brian: Thanks for the link. One may also be interested in a more recent post, http://karagila.org/2020/countable-sets-of-reals/

Answer (score 0):

Trichotomy of cardinals implies AC, see [here](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/news_old/monthly544-553.pdf) or [here](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Emorrow/336_12/papers/martha.pdf) e.g.

Your statement implies that trichotomy, I think. So the proof is not as direct as you'd like...

Comment: Why do you think this is related to the OP?

Comment: @JCAA yes. I’m showing a different approach.

Comment: This is not the question here. It's an open problem.