# Injections from all ordinals into a set $X$

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

We are working in $\mathsf{ZF}$. Let $X$ be a set. Let $A$ be the class of all injections $f: \alpha \to X$ for arbitrary ordinals $\alpha$.

I am quite sure that, in fact, $A$ is a set, since if not, there is an injection from every ordinal $\alpha$ into our set $X$. Hence, $X$ is too large to be a set and must be a class. Contradiction.

In $\mathsf{ZFC}$ it is quite clear, that $A$ is a set, since there cannot be an injection from $\alpha$ to $X$ if $|\alpha| > |X|$. Therefore, for all such $\alpha$ where there is an injection we have that $\alpha < |X|^+$, i.e. $A \subseteq  \mathcal{P}(|X|^+ \times X)$ and therefore $A$ is a set by separation.

The second argument makes use of $\mathsf{AC}$ since we need this to make sure that every set has a cardinality.

First of all, please let me know if I am right. If so, I would like to know how I can prove this by making use only of the axioms of $\mathsf{ZF}$. I tried to get a contradiction using the Replacement Scheme, but this did not seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You're absolutely wrong when you say that the second argument uses the fact that $A$ "has a cardinality"

The axiom of choice makes sure that every cardinality is an aleph number, but cardinality and its basic arithmetics have **absolutely** nothing to do with the axiom of choice. Every set has a cardinality, because cardinality of a set $A$ is just the class of all sets which have a bijection with $A$. If $A$ has a bijection with an ordinal, we can pick the least such ordinal as a representative to that cardinality, and for infinite ordinals we call these representatives $\aleph$ numbers.

But even if $A$ cannot be well-ordered, it still has a cardinality. Using the axiom of regularity we can even create sets which represent each cardinality, even if they are not well-ordered.

---

Now that we've cleared that issue, yes, you are right there is only set-many such injections.

Here we can use Hartogs' theorem, as mentioned by Brian. Or, we can just prove this directly.

Note that if $f\colon\alpha\to A$ is an injection, with $\alpha$ an ordinal, then the restrictions of $f$ to initial segments of $\alpha$ create a well-ordered chain of subsets of $A$, ordered by $\subseteq$ (from which we can also reconstruct $f$, since $f(\beta)$ is the unique element that lies in the difference of the $\beta+1$-th and the $\beta$-th set in the chain).

This means that we can ask how many chains of subsets of $A$ are well-ordered by $\subseteq$ with the difference between two successive sets is a singleton. Since the collection of these can be defined with a first-order formula in the language of set theory (albeit very long and tedious), the collection of all such chains is a subclass of $\mathcal{PPP}(A)$, so the collection of all injections from ordinals into $A$ is also a set.

(As a side note, we didn't gain much here, since this is around 83% of the proof of Hartogs theorem as it is...)

Comment: In our lecture, cardinality was defined as "If $x$ is a set, let $|x|$ denote the least ordinal $\alpha$ such that there is a bijection $f:\alpha \to x$, if this exists." Later, we proved that $|x|$ is in fact defined for every set $x$ using $\mathsf{AC}$ (implying the wellordering principle implying that cardinality is defined). So I thought that in $\mathsf{ZF}$ there are sets without a cardinality? I think you are using a different definition of cardinality - or are these in fact the same? (But then I don't understand why my lecturer did not prove the existence without $\mathsf{AC}$)

Comment: Many people don't know how to define the *cardinals* internally without the axiom of choice; many people believe that it's not important enough to talk about non-choice situations; many people simply confuse the idea of cardinality being an equivalence relation on sets, and cardinals being "material" representatives for each cardinality. I don't know who is your teacher, and I can't tell you why they did what they did. The point is that you were taught wrong. [Here is something I wrote on the topic](http://karagila.org/2013/the-philosophy-of-cardinality-pathologies-or-not/). [...]

Comment: [...] You can also find several questions and answers on this site on this very topic. [One](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/172326/622), [two](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53770/defining-cardinality-in-the-absence-of-choice), [three](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/53770/622), [four](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/53752/622), and there are probably even more.

Answer (score 2):

You want the [Hartogs number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartogs_number) of the set $X$: it’s the least well-ordered cardinal that can’t be injected into $X$, and its existence can be proved in $\mathsf{ZF}$.

Briefly, if $X$ is a set, so is

$$\mathscr{W}=\{\langle S,\preceq\rangle\in\wp(X)\times\wp(X\times X):S\subseteq X\text{ and }\preceq\text{ well-orders }X\}\;.$$

For each $\langle S,\preceq\rangle\in\mathscr{W}$ there is a unique ordinal $\alpha$ such that $\langle\alpha,\in\rangle$ is isomorphic to $\langle S,\preceq\rangle$, and the axiom schema of replacement ensures that the family of those ordinals is a set, $A$. It’s not hard to see that $A$ is in fact some ordinal $\alpha$, so it must be the least ordinal that can’t be injected into $X$, and it’s clear that it must in fact be a cardinal.